# How to disable theme updates in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, text-editor

I use Sublime Text 3, (build 3083) with Predawn theme. I tweaked Predawn theme a bit so I'd like to disable updates because every time I restart my PC and open ST3 again it checks for updates and overwrites my tweaks in Predawn.sublime-package file.

I put `"update_check": false;` in User settings but that didn't help.

Is there any way to disable theme updates?

Comment: You could save the modified file to your *Packages -> User* file, and it shouldn't get updated.

Comment: @saadq That's it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

`update_check` is for updates to Sublime Text itself, not for packages that are managed by Package Control.

To prevent auto-updates for packages, add the Predawn theme to Package Control's `auto_upgrade_ignore` list in [PC's settings](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/settings). Select *Preferences: Package Control Settings - User* from the Command Palette and add the line:

```
   "auto_upgrade_ignore": ["Predawn"],
```

Also, don't redirect `www.sublimetext.com` if you intend to visit the website again as this will prevent you from doing so.

Answer (score -2):

Windows host file:

```
127.0.0.1       www.sublimetext.com
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Search Notepad and open Notepad "As Administrator"
2. Go to this path "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts".
3. add line at last ..

   ```
    127.0.0.1       www.sublimetext.com
   ```
4. Save file and restart Sublime text 3 or PC.

[Note: hosts is a file]